# Filter a list of strings and return a list with only your friend's name in it

Tags: python, list

I'm learning Python and trying to solve the same problem ("Friend or Foe?"). I wrote the code below and would like to find out how to move-on following "my logic" way.

It seems that it adds just the very first item to the `new_friends` list but doesn't iterate over all the elements of `x` list.

Beside above, the return value is `None` ... what am I not noticing here?

```
def friend(x):
    x = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Jason", "Yous"]
    new_friends = []
    for str in x:
        if len(str) == 4:
            return new_friends.append(str)
    return new_friends[0:]
```

Instead of `if` statement I also tried a nested `while` loop .. but no success adding other items to the `new_friends` list.

Comment: append function returns None, by the way. Are you trying to return the list? Are you supposed to be adding new elements to it?

Comment: Note: you have a parameter of x, which you immediately overwrite. How is the function called, and what're you supposed to be returning?

Comment: `[f for f in x if len(f) == 4]` will get you a list of all strings of length 4...

Comment: The line `return new_friends.append(str)` is wrong for two reasons: a) `list..append()` doesn't return anything b) you're trying to return to early, before you've built the whole list. Just do the append. c) Anyway, all this can be handled in one line with a list comprehension: `[xx for xx in x if x in len(x) == 4]`

Comment: Thank you guys. All of these are extremely useful for me. Doing the list comprehension seems to be the clearest solution, but at my level it is not clear enough and won't just pop out of my mind :) Anyway ... I'm trying to understand and adopt it now! 
Will keep up doing as much practice as I can to make it clear!

Comment: Think I got it now ... it is actually way easier and cleaner this way!
Only one thing: 

As soon as I put it on the site as a solution, it sends me this error: 

' Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 3, in <module> Test.assert_equals(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark",]), ["Ryan", "Mark"]) TypeError: friend() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given ' 

If i understand right by the problem I've to put there exactly one parameter ... I tried 'x' , tried 'new_friends' NONE worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fixed up version of your function that does what I believe you want:

```
def friend(x):
    new_friends = []
    for str in x:
        if len(str) == 4:
            new_friends.append(str) # no 'return' here
    return new_friends # return resulting list.  no need to return a slice of it
```

Here's a more concise version that uses a list comprehension:

```
def friend(candidates):
    return [candidate for candidate in candidates if len(candidate) == 4]
```

For either version of the function, this:

```
print(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Jason", "Yous"]))
```

results in this:

```
['Ryan', 'Yous']
```

Comment: Dear Steve! Thank you so-so much! This is almost exactly what I wanted to do and I'll think about the "why" kind of questions stucked in me :)

Only one more thing. As soon as I put it on the site as a solution, it sends me this error:

'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(friend(["Ryan", "Kieran", "Mark",]), ["Ryan", "Mark"])
TypeError: friend() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

'

If i understand right by the problem I've to put there exactly one parameter ... I tried 'x' , tried 'new_friends'  NONE worked

Comment: The strange thing here is that I renamed `friend` to `friends`, and so you don't even have a function named `friend` in what I gave you.  Did you rename it back to `friend`?  If that's the case, then I think I see what's happening...The function is supposed to take the list to be filtered as a parameter.  You had a parameter originally, but then you overwrote it with the input data right in the function.  I'll change my answer to do what I think the system wants, including renaming the function(s).

Comment: Yes, I noticed it and fixed. I got this parameter issue as well. The thing I tried is very similar. I put the x parameter in the defined function and also in the {print} line and added  x = #list of names before/outside of the function as a global variable. (As far as I know it is not a good practice at all to have global variables if it comes to a more complex code, but this was the only way to filter through an existing list).